# Hide tableview sections on tap gesture of section header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to hide the NSArrays (menuItems, about, and charting) on the click for the specific section header for the tableview cell arrays. I got the section header to highlight and de-highlight depending on tap gesture recognizer count but I can not get the tableview cells to hide when that specific section header is clicked. Can someone please help? Thank you! Here is my .m code. My GCF float method is located at the bottom of the .m.

```
@interface SidebarTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SidebarTableViewController {

    NSArray *menuItems;
    NSArray *about;
    NSArray *charting;



}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuItems = @[@"Home",@"Field Goal", @"Punt", @"Kick Off", @"Snapper", @"Punter"];

    about = @[@"Home",@"About Us", @"Tutorial"];

    charting = @[@"Home",@"Charting"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1) {
            NSString *CellIdentifier2 = [charting objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell2;

    }
    else {
        NSString *CellIdentifier1 = [about objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell1;

    }
}


#pragma mark - Navigation


// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];


    }



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3 ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section==0)
    {
        return [menuItems count];

    }
    else if(section==1)
    {
        return [charting count];

    }
    else{
        return [about count];
    }
}



- (UIView*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView viewForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if(section == 0){
        headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Timers Without Charting"];
    }
    else if(section==1)
    {
        headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Charting with Timers"];

    }
    else{
        headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"About Us/Tutorial"];
    }

    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.width, tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(catchHeaderGesture:)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    return headerLabel;

    //return nil;
}


-(void)catchHeaderGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    border ++;
    if (border == 1)

    {

        UILabel *caughtLabel = (UILabel*)sender.view;

        caughtLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
        caughtLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;




    }

    if (border == 2 )

    {

        UILabel *caughtLabel = (UILabel*)sender.view;
        caughtLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        caughtLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    border = 0;

    }

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    border ++;
    if (border == 1)

    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.hidden = YES;
        return 40.0;




    }

    if (border == 2 )

    {  border = 0;

        UITableViewCell* cell = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.hidden = YES;


    }

    return 0;


}


@end
```

Comment: How do you hide an abstract programming class that isn't visible in any way, shape or form?  Is this a Zen question?

Comment: It's not about hiding the NSArrays as a class it's about hiding the Tableview cells within the section that hold the NSArray data.

Comment: My comment was a (too-subtle, apparently) hint that your title is rather misleading.  (edit) I see you changed it,.

Comment: Yea I just realized that it was a pretty bad title I just changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a few couple things to make this work.

- section headers that respond to taps.
- a method for expanding or collapsing a section.
- some way to track which sections are collapsed.

The first is trivial.  Return a `UIView` for the header, and attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it.  You'll need a method to figure out which section it is.  You can use the `tag` property, or you can store the views in an `NSMutableArray`.

In `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you return 0 if the section is collapsed, or the actual number, if not.

In the handler for the gesture recognizer, you toggle the collapsed/expanded state, and then you call `[self.tableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] to update the visuals.

(I do see in your posted code that you already handle part of this.)